# Fault when operating on double/float on STM32F4

Tags: c, assembly, arm, stm32, fpu

I am working with STM32F407 microcontroller.

```
void mya_usart_init(USART_Type* USARTx, uint32_t baudRate, uint8_t UsartClockSpeedMHz) {

    double a = (double)72/7;
    double b = (double)UsartClockSpeedMHz;

//    usart_div = (double)UsartClockSpeedMHz; //  * 1000000 / (8 * (2) * baudRate);
//
//    USARTx->BRR |= ((uint32_t)usart_div << 4) | (uint32_t) round(((usart_div - (uint32_t)usart_div) * 16)) ; // seperate integer part and decimal part
//
//    // USARTx->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_M; // this is reset value already
//
//    USARTx->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_UE; // Rx, Tx, and USART enable

    return;
}
```

I have been dealing with USART, then I figured out that I cannot make this conversion from `uint8_t` to `double`. As seen from below, variable `a` is successfully gets its value, however, the variable `b` cannot be written with the desired value. I have added the assembly code, everything goes well but at this stage;

```
08000ac4:   bl      0x800046c <__floatunsidf>
```

The MCU enters a fault with the following error in IDE(Eclipse based STM32CubeIDE).

```
No source available for "__floatunsidf() at 0x800046c"
```

I also noticed that, this assembly line above does not appear for `(double)72/7` but appears for `(double)UsartClockSpeedMHz`. Why is that so?

**So, to me, while it can convert `72/7` to double, it cannot, for some reason, convert `UsartClockSpeedMHz`, which is 84, given as an argument to the function, to double. What is the reason for this?**

Thanks.

[image]

```
 6        void mya_usart_init(USART_Type* USARTx, uint32_t baudRate, uint8_t UsartClockSpeedMHz) {
          mya_usart_init:
08000aa8:   push    {r4, r7, lr}
08000aaa:   sub     sp, #36 ; 0x24
08000aac:   add     r7, sp, #0
08000aae:   str     r0, [r7, #12]
08000ab0:   str     r1, [r7, #8]
08000ab2:   mov     r3, r2
08000ab4:   strb    r3, [r7, #7]
10            double a = (double)72/7;
08000ab6:   add     r4, pc, #32     ; (adr r4, 0x8000ad8 <mya_usart_init+48>)
08000ab8:   ldrd    r3, r4, [r4]
08000abc:   strd    r3, r4, [r7, #24]
11            double b = (double)UsartClockSpeedMHz;
08000ac0:   ldrb    r3, [r7, #7]
08000ac2:   mov     r0, r3
08000ac4:   bl      0x800046c <__floatunsidf>
08000ac8:   mov     r3, r0
08000aca:   mov     r4, r1
08000acc:   strd    r3, r4, [r7, #16]
21            return;
08000ad0:   nop     
22        }
```

---

update:

The build command is:

```
18:14:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS ****
make -j8 all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Src/mya_usart.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DSTM32 -DSTM32F407G_DISC1 -DSTM32F4 -DSTM32F407VGTx -DDEBUG -c -I../Inc -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Src/mya_usart.d" -MT"Src/mya_usart.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Src/mya_usart.o"
../Src/mya_usart.c: In function 'mya_usart_init':
../Src/mya_usart.c:11:12: warning: unused variable 'b' [-Wunused-variable]
     double b = (float)UsartClockSpeedMHz;
            ^
../Src/mya_usart.c:10:12: warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-variable]
     double a = (float)72/7;
            ^
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"/home/muyustan/Documents/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.3.0/MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS/STM32F407VGTX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
Finished building target: MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.elf
 
arm-none-eabi-objdump -h -S  MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.elf  > "MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.list"
arm-none-eabi-objcopy  -O binary  MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.elf  "MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.bin"
arm-none-eabi-size   MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.elf 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2804       8    1568    4380    111c MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.elf
Finished building: default.size.stdout
Finished building: MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.bin
 
 
Finished building: MYA-STM32F4-DRIVERS.list
```

---

I cannot even perform this in main(),

```
for (i=0 ; i<15; i++){

        f*=10.01;

}
```

I get `No source available for "__extendsfdf2() at 0x80004b0"` for the above one.

If I change it to, (notice the 10.01*f*)

```
for (i=0 ; i<15; i++){

        f*=10.01f;

}
```

This time, assembly code changes:

```
83 f*=10.01f;
080002fc:   vldr    s15, [r7]
08000300:   vldr    s14, [pc, #44]  ; 0x8000330 <main+288>
08000304:   vmul.f32        s15, s15, s14
08000308:   vstr    s15, [r7]
0800030c:   ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
0800030e:   adds    r3, #1
08000310:   str     r3, [r7, #4]
08000312:   ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
08000314:   cmp     r3, #14
08000316:   ble.n   0x80002fc <main+236>
```

Executing the very first step, `vldr s15, [r7]` routes me to the following screen:

[image]

Comment: `No source available` is not a runtime error as such. It's unclear where your fault is. In the screenshot you have not even entered into `__floatunsidf` yet.

Comment: @Jester fault occurs right after I execute the line `08000ac4:   bl      0x800046c <__floatunsidf>`

Comment: It looks like your compiler does not know how to generate code to convert integer to `float`, so it's calling a library function to do it.  That isn't needed for the previous line since the value is constant and so the conversion is done at compile time.  That doesn't explain why it faults, though.  Do you have any more information about the address of the fault and the type?  Can you single-step into the `__floatunsidf` function (by instructions, not by source lines)?

Comment: I don't know a lot about ARM, but according to https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00047230-floating-point-unit-demonstration-on-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf, this chip can only do single-precision floating point in hardware.  So any operations on `double` are going to have to be done in software, or emulated.  I wonder if you have got this set up properly in your compiler.  Can you describe the details of your build process and runtime environment: what compiler, what version, what options, how are you running the code?

Comment: Are you able to do any other `double` arithmetic successfully?  (Again, making sure that it's something that cannot be done at compile time or optimized out.)

Comment: @NateEldredge no I cannot do any (double) casting at runtime, I tried at different places in code. I also figured out that, if I try (float) instead of (double), this time I fall into the fault at the assembly instruction of `08000a02:   vmov    s15, r3`. Just after executing this, again fault occurs.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am adding the build command to my question

Comment: I note the documentation for `-mfloat-abi` says: "Note that the hard-float and soft-float ABIs are not link-compatible; you must compile your entire program with the same ABI, and link with a compatible set of libraries."  I wonder if libgcc, where `__floatunsidf` is defined, is expecting the soft-float ABI.  Does it work if you build with `-mfloat-abi=soft` or `=softfp`?

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not sure if I am doing it right or not, but if I am, when I try `soft`, it enters fault right at startup, and when I try `softp` nothing changes with respect to `hard`

Comment: Okay.  Maybe someone else will come along who knows about ARM floating point.

Comment: But you may want to change the title to focus on the fault itself, e.g. "Fault when operating on double on STM32F4".  As was noted, the "No source available" message has nothing to do with the problem, and only means that the debugger doesn't have the source of libgcc to show you.  (And by the way, you still haven't said exactly what type of fault it is - that will surely be important information for an expert.)

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you for your interest, I am not really well qualified in assembling linking etc. I did some more edits, however it started to turn into a garbage. I hope someone could understand what is wrong. I am almost sure that back then I was able to use floating point calculations on runtime on same mcu.

Comment: @NateEldredge ok, it turns out that FPU(floating point unit) has to be enabled first........... I am writing everything on my own except startup file, and it looks like it wasn't containing the FPU initialization sequence..

Comment: That was going to be my comment is did you enable the fpu copressor?  And then which coprocessors are available and then did you build properly for that?

Comment: @old_timer I did not know fpu is disabled by default. I found some assembly code and inserted it into startup file. But I wonder would it be done in C code too. I guess it should've, but did not tried.